# what does a topic get when 2 nodes publish to it?

Tags: ros, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If 2 nodes are publishing to the topic l_leg_uhz_position_controller/command what would the joint do? try doing both?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49313/what-does-a-topic-get-when-2-nodes-publish-to-it?/) by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2012-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, messages from multiple publishers get interleaved, with no reasonable way to predict the order in which they will be received. In some cases that can be quite useful, for example when aggregating rosout or diagnostic messages.

As @Ben_S said, the semantics of mixing controller messages depend entirely on that controller's implementation. Most likely it will get confused.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In such a case, most likely the last received command will override any previous ones. If you would like to know the behaviour of a specific controller, i would advise to have a look at the documentation or ultimately at the source code itself if the case isnt mentioned in the docs.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-11-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pk99](https://answers.ros.org/users/73613/pk99/) on 2021-04-27**:
How to correct this? If a topic has 2 publishers but the user needs only a single node to publish? I'm having a similar problem where a certain topic has 2 publishers to it and is malfunctioning